# What does Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy0 to required type means?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

i`m facing an error in my Spring Batch code which says:
Error creating bean with name 'itemReader' defined in class path resource, Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy0 to required type for property 'preparedStatementSetter'.

This is my ItemReader code:

```
<beans:bean id="itemReader"
 class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="sql" value="select * from Trans_Tst WHERE id =?"/>
    <beans:property name="rowMapper" ref="romMapper"/>
    <beans:property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="ReaderSqlParameterSetter"/>
</beans:bean>



<beans:bean id="ReaderSqlParameterSetter"
 class="sa.com.anb.itg.dev.settlement.batch.ReaderSqlParameterSetter" scope="step">
<beans:property name="id" value="#{jobParameters[id]}"/>
</beans:bean>
```

and this is my ReaderSqlParameterSetter class:

```
package sa.com.anb.itg.dev.settlement.batch;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.ItemPreparedStatementSetter;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ReaderSqlParameterSetter implements
 ItemPreparedStatementSetter<transactionas>{

    public void setValues(transactionas transactionas,PreparedStatement ps) 
          throws SQLException {
        ps.setInt(1, transactionas.GetID());

    } 

}

<beans:bean id="jdbcWriter" 
  class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 
    <beans:property name="sql" value="update Trans_Tst set ()amount) values (?) 
           where id= ?"/>
    <beans:property name="preparedStatementSetter" 
          ref="WriterSqlParameterSetter"/> 
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="WriterSqlParameterSetter" 
  class="sa.com.anb.itg.dev.settlement.batch.WriterSqlParameterSetter" scope="step">
    <beans:property name="amount" value="#{jobParameters[amount]}"/>
    <beans:property name="id" value="#{jobParameters[id]}"/>  
</beans:bean>



    public class WriterSqlParameterSetter implements PreparedStatementSetter {

    transactionas transactionas = new transactionas();

    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
        ps.setDouble(1, transactionas.GetAmount());
        ps.setInt(2, transactionas.GetID());

    } 

}
```

Can Anyone help me please?

Comment: It means you are trying to inject a proxied object into some property called 'preparedStatementSetter', but the types are not matching up.  Without seeing the code for the setter, or how it's being injected, my best guess is that you are referencing 'preparedStatementSetter' by its concrete class and not it's interface.  Were possible, you should always use the interface as your reference holder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the missing code, any farther tips please?

Comment: How is your AOP stuff setup?  I think if you use CGLibs it creates the proxies differently than that standard JDK way.

Comment: the problem is that i`m new to spring batch (my first project) and i dont know what are you talking about. BTW i`m using maven if thats what your talking about! lol

Comment: In a nutshell, what is happening is that a "proxy" is being generated for your ReaderSqlParameterSetter class.  A proxy object is used to wrapper a real class for various reasons.  I think in your case it's because you set the scope to "step" on the ReaderSqlParameterSetter.  According to the JavaDoc, using Step Scope turns on AOP Scoped Proxy.  This speaks to AOP Proxies better: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the right interface.  Your ReaderSqlParameterSetter  should implements **PreparedStatementSetter** not *ItemPreparedStatementSetter*

If you look at the impl of JdbcCursorItemReader:

```
public class JdbcCursorItemReader<T> extends AbstractCursorItemReader<T> {

PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

PreparedStatementSetter preparedStatementSetter;

String sql;

RowMapper rowMapper;
```

The property is a PreparedStatementSetter .

If you look at the interface you try to use :

```
public interface ItemPreparedStatementSetter<T> {
/**
 * Set parameter values on the given PreparedStatement as determined from
 * the provided item.
 * @param ps the PreparedStatement to invoke setter methods on
 * @throws SQLException if a SQLException is encountered (i.e. there is no
 * need to catch SQLException)
 */
void setValues(T item, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException;

}
```

This interface does NOT extends PreparedStatementSetter ...

So it does not work.  If you would have not put the scope=step, you would have probably had a ClassCastException kind of error!

Comment: I corrected the code but its giving me another error which is "Error setting property values, Bean property 'preparedStatementSetter' is not writable or has an invalid setter method"

Comment: Hehe... you simply forgot to write a setter in your implementation.  Happen all the time ;-)

Comment: do you still have the scope=step?

Comment: I do have the inplementation but i didnt post it. it simeler to the readerSetter. yes i do still have scope=step.

Comment: i added the code of the writer up there in the main post to clear up things to you

Comment: the error now is about the ItemWriter`s PreparedStatementSetter

Comment: Yeah, just to make it easy... the ItemWriter (JdbcBatchItemWriter) use the ItemPreparedStatementSetter you used in the reader !!!  So NOW you have to use it lol.

Comment: Thank you very much cygnusx you were very helpful to me and that shows how good you are in spring batch :) I corrected the code but now its showing the same error that i was getting in the beginning "fialed to convert $proxy0". I dont know is the value of properties of the WriterSqlParameterSetter that causing the error or?

Comment: I posted this problem in a new question just to let you have the credit so i dont waste your time and you get credits too 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025088/what-does-failed-to-convert-property-value-of-type-proxy0-to-required-type-mea)

Comment: just to be sure... try removing the scope=step in your StatementSetters, (just hardcode the amount and id for the moment). If you dont have the error anymore, i would suggest another way deal with the jobParameters.!  In another project i made, i have created a simple Pojo i called myBatchContext (Default Spring Bean - singleton) and wrote data i needed across my batch in that object.  This way, you dont need to put the scope=step in other beans that need jobParameters... you only need to autowire the myBatchContext ref.